# Lower triangular matrix transform to upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Given a 3D non-rectangular box as a lower triangular matrix $\mathbf{A}_L$ with multiple points in it. Is it possible to transform the matrix $\mathbf{A}_L$ to an upper triangular matrix $\mathbf{A}_U$ while preserving the distances and angles of points being in the box? A transpose will give an upper triangular matrix but does not seem to preserve the distances and angles of points within the box.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: In what way does this matrix correspond to a box (for instance, do the rows give the coordinates of the corners)? Which "distances" are you talking about?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, each row denotes one corner vector. Hence, the three vectors span a box. The distance is the Euclidean distance between points.

Comment: By "box", do you mean [parallelpiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped)? Is the box "spanned" by the vectors the parallelpiped whose edges have the length and direction of the three vectors?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $\mathbf A_L$ has three rows, and that the "box" of interest is the [parallelpiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) "generated" by these rows.

If all that is correct, then one solution is to take $\mathbf A_U[i,j] = \mathbf A_L[4-i,4-j]$, where $M[i,j]$ denotes the $i,j$ entry of $M$ for $i,j = 1,2,3$.